# Using directory structure for robot Framework test with pycharm

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I want to run tests in Robot Framework with my defined directory structure

I would also like the following kind of directory structure for the robot framework tests:

```
Root directory
Libraries
     Library.py
Resource Files
      Resource.txt
Tests
      test_1.txt
      test_2.txt
```

However, I do not know how to write my tests so they can access my library and resource files. For example, how to import Resource\Resource.txt from Tests\test_1.txt.

Is there any possibility to globally set the directory of the Resources File in Pycharm without defining any variable in the test file? What i trying to do it just write only this:

Resource   Resource.txt

in the test file

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure is quite normal one, and both Robot Framework and Pycharm will work OK with it.

When importing the files in each other, use a relative path to them. As "Libraries", "Resource Files" and "Tests" are sibling directories, that would mean using `..` ("go up to my parent directory") and then specifying the location to the target file from there.
For example:

```
Resource   ../Resource Files/resource.txt
Library        ../Libraries/Library.py
```